# publishing an app in the Apple's Appstore for a client

Tags: ios, app-store

we are developing iOS apps for several clients.

Not all of them have registered in the apple development program.

is it at all possible for us to publish the app using our account, but have their name and contact information display in the appstore.

Comment: If it's a great app why not publish it under your development account.  Consider this part of the service for your client.

Comment: @bbarnhart I wouldn't do it even if it was the best app ever. Its not like publish and done, there are much more things involved like splitting revenue, dealing with Apple, publishing updates etc.

Comment: @JustSid - Those sound like billable items to me.  However, if the client does not have budget for it then it's just a lot easier for the client to have their own account.

Comment: @bbarnhart A client that doesn't have and obviously also doesn't want a $99 account doesn't sound like it would pay say monthly bills...

Comment: the client decided to go with his own account :)

Comment: why was this closed as off topic? it might not be a strict technical question, but it relates to our work as coders. where can a question like this be posted then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your company would be listed as publisher. But you will be able to put their URLs and support information and anything in the description area.

Answer (score 3):

No, thats not possible besides custom support and web URLs. But if your client is serious, they should be able to afford the $99 for the account. Are you sure that want to do this anyway? Its your account after all, so you show up with the App and all of its reputation and reviews etc. I wouldn't want to have my clients apps in my normal dev account.

Comment: true. :) very good answer. a pity i cannot mark both as the accepted answer